# Android - add extra height to wrap_content

Tags: android, xml

I'm using wrap_content on my layout to dynamically change its size depending on the contents, however the problem is that the shadows get cut off.

I tried using padding, but the shadows are still cut off. Is there a way to add a value to wrap_content? like for example wrap_content + 6dp or something.

Comment: Try to use `margin` instead of `padding`

Answer (score 0):

set up `marginBottom` for last `View` in your `ViewGroup` (e.g. `LinearLayout`), not padding for this `ViewGroup`/parent. this may be tricky as you wrote you are changing content, thus you may add/remove `View`s - keep track and add/remove bottom margin to last child in that case

you probably also should take care of horizontal margins and even top one, as "shadow" is in fact [appearing around whole `View`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/shadows-clipping), not only below